# Listen to Me (Hollies) - what is that last line?

Tags: lyrics

In the song Listen to Me, all the lyrics sites end each verse with:

> very soon you've forgotten, that you didn't care about love.

That’s not the way it sounds to me. More like “that you can’t buy love”. Certainly there aren’t as many syllables, and I can’t see how to make the other version fit.

So, what is that last line?

Answer (score 1):

Based on listening to the recording below and watching Allan Clarke's lips, it seems very clear that he's singing "...that you don't care about love."

However, it's easy to see where it might be heard differently. He actually sings something along the lines of "tha yewdn ca ba la". In the absence of clearly enunciated consonants, it could be heard as "that you can't buy love."

The key to hearing it as "that you don't care about love" is catching the very brief "dn" at the end of "you". It comes off as a slightly percussive sound, adding a rhythmic moment that wouldn't be present in "that you can't buy love".